# Simply Question on Arrays in Ruby - Extra Array Element Upon Creation and When Working With Array Data

Tags: arrays, ruby, data-structures, integer

```
# For example, the base [1, 4, 6] gives us the following pyramid
#     15
#   5   10
# 1   4    6

def pyramid_sum(base)
  pyramid = [base]
  new_level = []
  prev_level = []
  base.length.times { |x|
    prev_level = pyramid[0]
    new_level = build(prev_level)
    pyramid.unshift(new_level)
  } 
  return pyramid
end

def build(level)
  new_level = []
  level.each_with_index { |num, index|
    if index < level.length-1
      new_level <<level[index] + level[index+1]
    end
  }
  return new_level
end

print pyramid_sum([1, 4, 6]) #=> [[15], [5, 10], [1, 4, 6]]
puts

print pyramid_sum([3, 7, 2, 11]) #=> [[41], [19, 22], [10, 9, 13], [3, 7, 2, 11]]
puts
```

Outputs:
**
[[], [15], [5, 10], [1, 4, 6]]
[[], [41], [19, 22], [10, 9, 13], [3, 7, 2, 11]]
**

Why is there always an extra [] (empty array) in the front of the 2D array? I have seen this many times in my results with arrays in Ruby and though it is simple I can't seem to figure out why that extra annoying array is always there? I KNOW this is simple and I may delete this question if it warrants such but why is there an extra array element in the front of my array? It seems like to merely create an array is it always have an extra element in it and I can't "truly" modify it because everything in Ruby is an object anyways.

Comment: The way you have indented your code makes it practically unreadable, so I will not go through it. However, the simple answer to the question "why is there an empty array" is "because you programmed it that way".

Comment: How do you suggest I indent my code?

Comment: See [this recent SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70464801/2-d-array-pyramid-in-ruby/70467650#70467650).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a first step, I have reformatted your code a bit and removed some useless code as well. (For example, the assignments to `new_level` and `prev_level` in `pyramid_sum` are useless, since they are immediately re-assigned in the block anyway.)

```ruby
def pyramid_sum(base)
  pyramid = [base]

  base.length.times do
    prev_level = pyramid.first
    new_level = build(prev_level)
    pyramid.unshift(new_level)
  end

  pyramid
end

def build(level)
  new_level = []

  level.each_index do |index|
    if index < level.length - 1
      new_level << level[index] + level[index + 1]
    end
  end

  new_level
end
```

With those useless assignments removed, the two lines that create the problem are right below each other, and the problem pretty much already jumps out:

- The height of your pyramid should always be the same as the width of the base.
- You pre-initialize the result variable with the original base as the first level of the pyramid.
- But then you iterate the `build` method `base.length` times, i.e. *in addition* to the one level you have pre-initialized, you *add* another `base.length` levels … and as a result, you end up with one level too many: you build as many levels as you need but you had already put another level into the result.

The solution for that is simple: iterate `base.length - 1` times:

```ruby
def pyramid_sum(base)
  pyramid = [base]

  (base.length-1).times do
    prev_level = pyramid.first
    new_level = build(prev_level)
    pyramid.unshift(new_level)
  end

  pyramid
end

def build(level)
  new_level = []

  level.each_index do |index|
    if index < level.length - 1
      new_level << level[index] + level[index + 1]
    end
  end

  new_level
end
```

Note that this problem almost *screams* for recursion. Something like this:

```ruby
def pyramid_sum(*base) = pyramid_rec([base]).reverse

def pyramid_rec(pyramid)
  return pyramid if pyramid.last.size <= 1

  pyramid_rec(pyramid << pyramid.last.each_cons(2).map(&:sum))
end

puts pyramid_sum(1, 4, 6)
puts pyramid_sum(3, 7, 2, 11)
```

Comment: Thank you. Also you are correct, I was thinking of implementing a recursive solution because it is essentially asking for it but I wanted to solve it with respect to the information taught for the problem.

Answer (score 2):

The reason why you get that extra empty array at the start is because you tell the `pyramid_sum` function to add `base.length` more levels to the base.

A pyramid made up in this fashion will have as many levels as it has items in its base.

So that means that when you write `base.length.times { |x| ... }`, you are essentially saying that you will be adding `base.length` new *extra* levels on top of the base level.

For your first example, `[1, 4, 6]`, this means that you say that on top of this base layer, you will add three more layers:

- First, you will sum up the base layer in parts, adding `[5, 10]`
- Second, you will sum up the new, second layer in parts, adding `[15]`
- Lastly, you will *attempt* to sum up that third layer in parts, and this will result in the `[]`

The reason is that when you try to sum up that third layer, there is not enough items in it to add any two numbers from the layer below. Therefore, you will end up adding the empty `new_layer = []` that you haven't modified.

If you want to fix this, you can either run the iteration `(base.length - 1).times`, or you can add an `if` statement as a guard to not add any generated empty layers:

```rb
new_level = build(prev_layer)
if new_level.length > 0
  pyramid.unshift(new_level)
end
```